# Android Studio: Simple BaseAdapter Setup Fail

Tags: android, adapter

I would like to create a simple populated GridView using BaseAdapter but I keep getting empty list - application runs but there are no Views displayed.
Below are all files are use for this task:

**Main**:

```
String[] items = {"Some", "items", "to", "display"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);

    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**MyAdapter**:

LayoutInflater inflater;

```
Context context;
String[] myData;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] myData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myData = myData;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return myData[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, parent, false);
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText(myData[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.random.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="40dip"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="100dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**grid.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have checked in various sources countles times and I did not manage to find an error in my code. It would be amazing if someone would take a look at it and find a reason for empty activity as the reason is probably obvious.

Comment: please check my ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getCount method always return 0. Return the number of elements in your myData array instead.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myData.length;
}
```

Comment: After doing that I receive an "Application fail to open" error with logcat: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.random, PID: 3385
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.android.random.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:42)

Comment: your layout inflater is null. Replace inflater.inflate with  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate

Answer (score 1):

You can try this my friend

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
String[] data;


public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] myData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = myData;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);
        }

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText(data[position]);
    return convertView;

}
}
```